# how to get profileId in google analytics using SSIS package

Tags: c#, ssis, google-analytics

I am gettin google analytics data using SSIS GoogleAnalytics Source plugin. Basically I am looping multiple accounts and inserting data into SQL database. I would like to insert also profileId used for the request. But it seems like neither dimensions nor metrics results have it. Anyone knows how I can get it and insert into DB?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out that I can pass it as an user definied variable with a format @[user::profileId] by adding a new output column on data flow component(in my case I used a Data Flow Component between googeanalyticsGoogleAnalytics Source and OLE DB destination tools.)